# Missing Symbols RtlGetFrame, RtlPushFrame, RtlPopFrame

Tags: windows, winapi, symbols

I'd like to use some undocumented symbols that listed in `ProcessHacker` project. taken from Here:

https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntpebteb.h#L241
https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntrtl.h#L7156

However, I don't know to which dll do they belong...

In project readme page, it's said that I only need the latest windows SDK, but after compilation I get :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) struct 
_TEB_ACTIVE_FRAME * __cdecl RtlGetFrame(void)" (__imp_?
RtlGetFrame@@YAPEAU_TEB_ACTIVE_FRAME@@XZ) referenced in function "public: static
 struct _TEB_ACTIVE_FRAME * __cdecl _RTL_FRAME::get(struct 
_TEB_ACTIVE_FRAME_CONTEXT const *)" (?
get@_RTL_FRAME@@SAPEAU_TEB_ACTIVE_FRAME@@PEBU_TEB_ACTIVE_FRAME_CONTEXT@@@Z) 
TestReentrancy  C:\projects\2.3\unit_tests\InjectionTest\Project1\main.obj  1
```

Perhaps anybody can tell me how to adjust my project configuration to make it work ? thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those functions are exported from `ntdll.dll` file. To link with those functions, add `#pragma comment (lib, "ntdll.lib")` in the source file. Or in Visual Studio, first check the active Configuration and Platform. Then add the library in Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies. For example, like this `%(AdditionalDependencies); ntdll.lib`. For mingw, cygwin, msys2 etc. toolchains (where GCC is used), use `-lntdll` option in command.

Or the functions can be written directly in the source code also without importing those from ntdll. Those functions use members from [Thread Information Block (TEB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block) as follows:

```
PTEB_ACTIVE_FRAME RtlGetFrame()
{
    return NtCurrentTeb()->ActiveFrame;
}

void RtlPushFrame(PTEB_ACTIVE_FRAME Frame)
{
    struct _TEB *Teb;

    Teb = NtCurrentTeb();
    Frame->Previous = Teb->ActiveFrame;
    Teb->ActiveFrame = Frame;
}

void RtlPopFrame(PTEB_ACTIVE_FRAME Frame)
{
NtCurrentTeb()->ActiveFrame = Frame->Previous;
}
```

Comment: Btw, this works for a (quite a) handful of functions, but last I checked the `ntdll.lib` was fairly incomplete.